# ¿Cómo evitar "unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'float' and 'float'" en división simple PYTHON?

Tags: python, condiciones

Estoy realizando una división simple en lectura de teclado de dos valor, pero quiero meter dentro de una condición que no se puedan ingresar valores 0. Al hacerlo me marca el error "if valor_uno | valor_dos = 0:    SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

```
valor_uno = float(input('Ingresa primer valor: '))
valor_dos = float(input('Ingresa segundo valor: '))
if valor_uno | valor_dos == 0:
print('No puedes dividir entre "0"')
else:
resultado = float(valor_uno/valor_dos)
print('El resultado de la division es: ',resultado)
```

Comment: En tu if a `valor_uno` contra que lo comparas?, hace falta algo no?

Comment: Tanto valor_uno ó valor_dos los igualo con 0.

Comment: Podría sustituirlo por    if valor_uno == 0 & valor_dos == 0:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observaciones:

- El operador `OR` en python lo vas a identificar por la palabra reservada `or`
- Como no puedes hacer una divisón por 0, entonces deberías indicar en el `if` que si el `valor1` o `valor2` son `0` devuelves un mensaje
- En tu `if` a la comparación del lado izquierdo me parece lke hace falta completarla, pues solo indicas el nombre de la variable pero no escribes que tipo de comparación haría

Considero debería quedar así:

```
valor_uno = float(input('Ingresa primer valor: '))
valor_dos = float(input('Ingresa segundo valor: '))
if valor_uno == 0 or valor_dos == 0:
  print('No puedes dividir entre "0"')
else:
  resultado = float(valor_uno/valor_dos)
  print('El resultado de la division es: ',resultado)
```

Te recomendaría esta [lectura de operadores](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html)

Comment: Gracias, esto me ha funcionado y debería leer la lectura de operadores para comprender mejor como funcionan en python. MUCHAS GRACIAS¡